# Jquery calculation works but adds incorrect value before correct value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working on this calculator and it's working in the sense it's correctly calculating the price of the field and displaying it. The problem though is that it appears to append the correct answer to another value (presumably taken from the data-price as they correlate).

Here's the code I have for it:

```js
var updateTotal = function() {
 
    var sumtotal;
       var sum = 0;
    //Add each product price to total
    $(".extraproduct").each(function() {
        var extra_price = $(this).data('price');
        var quantity = $('.extraQuantity', this).val();
   
        //Total for one product
        var subtotal = extra_price*quantity;     
         //Round to 2 decimal places.
        subtotal = subtotal.toFixed(2);      
        //Display subtotal in HTML element
        $('.productTotal', this).html(subtotal);
    });
    // total
       $('.productTotal').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).html());
    }); 
    
    $('#sum').html(sum.toFixed(2));
};
//Update total when quantity changes
$(".extraQuantity").bind("keyup change", function() {
    updateTotal();
});
//Update totals when page first loads
updateTotal();
// set this from local
    $('span.productTotal').each(function() {
        $(this).before("£")
    }); 
// unit price
   $('.extraproduct span').each(function() {
       var $price = $(this).parents("div").data('price');
      $(this).before($price);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="quote-label">Product 1</span>
<div class="input-wrap currency extraproduct" data-price="450.00">
<input type="number" class="extraQuantity" value="0"  min="1" max="20" />
<span class="productTotal"></span>
</div>
                
 <span class="quote-label">Product 2</span>
<div class="input-wrap currency extraproduct" data-price="10.00">
<input type="number" class="extraQuantity" value="0"  min="1" max="20" />
<span class="productTotal"></span>
</div>


            
 <span class="quote-label">Additional Product</span>
<div class="input-wrap checkbox-wrap extraproduct" data-price="5.00"><input type="checkbox" class="extraQuantity" value="0" />
<span class="productTotal"></span>
</div>

<div id="total">Total: £<span id="sum">0.00</span> </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DigitalAdam/5fLb0vnp/26/

I thought it could be to do with the subtotal.toFixed part but had no luck when adjusting or removing that. Any help is appreciated.
Regards

Comment: first little remark, you are using .keyup(function(), but nothing happens when i am using the little arrows for type="number" input fields. you should use onChange or onBlur events i think.

Comment: found another little mistake:  <div class="quote-label">Additional Product</span> you are opening a div but closing a span. tbh you should go through your html again as there are several little errors like that. at least in what you posted here

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'd been playing around with it a fair bit and should've rechecked before posting. I binded keyup with change to trigger on both events. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very Simple solution:
you are just using the .productTotal spans to calculate something. You could just set the display to none. It can still be used for calculations but it will now show:

```
.productTotal {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: That worked a treat. So simple. I was so fixated on the HTML and JS that I didn't even stop to consider a CSS fix. Thanks!